# Receive database connection error when trying to locally debug .net MVC4 app with multiple projects

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application that has a project that contains my .edmx file along with the models that map to it.  In a separate project, I have a Web Front end.  When I build the package and deploy, everything works great, but when I try to debug it locally, I get this error:

The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

I have looked at all the questions that show up on Stack overflow and MSDN forums regarding this problem, but none of the solutions have worked.  I have copied the connection string from the app.config to the web.config and it still doesn't work.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does the ConnectionString look like?